# WSRP - Server was unable to process request. Security Validation failed at Sharepoint Server

Tags: sharepoint, soap, web-config, liferay, wsrp

I'm trying to implement a WSRP (web services for remote portlets) solution. I want to consume webparts with a portal.

## Enviroment

#### SERVER 1:

CentOS 5, Liferay 5.2.3/Tomcat 6, portlet WSRP consumer.

#### SERVER 2:

Windows Server 2008, Sharepoint 2007, WSE 2 SP 3, SharePoint Producer Web Service version 1.0 (WSRP producer).

Both servers in the same intranet.

## Error

```
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing"xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">

<soap:Header>

  <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing/fault</wsa:Action>

  <wsa:MessageID>uuid:8ebd064c-2c44-4108-a196-fccef5a0f8e4</wsa:MessageID>

  <wsa:RelatesTo>uuid:ff042f75-c6a0-4a5f-b456-d7e0f3975c76</wsa:RelatesTo>

  <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>

  <wsse:Security>

    <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-5d15e3f9-5ef2-47e4-b85d-5f69432bf791">

      <wsu:Created>2009-09-08T17:51:51Z</wsu:Created>

      <wsu:Expires>2009-09-08T18:01:51Z</wsu:Expires>

    </wsu:Timestamp>

  </wsse:Security>

</soap:Header>

<soap:Body>

  <soap:Fault>

    <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>

    <faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---> Security Validation failed at Sharepoint Server</faultstring>

    <detail />

  </soap:Fault>

</soap:Body>
```

Please I need help. Do you need more information?. Thank you.

Comment: Is this an example of the dreaded double hop issue, where the user credentials are not being passed to the SharePoint server?

Comment: Nat, could you tell me how can I pass the user credentials to SharePoint server? Is is through web.config? What should it say? I am using WSRP producer with WSS, does it works with WSS or do I need MOSS (Microsoft Office SharePoint Server)? Thank you.